# How can I undo a recommendation?

Tags: feature-request, votes

I upvoted an answer too hastily; its last paragraph turned out to contain some irrelevant, debatable stuff.  I tried to undo the recommendation but the only way I found to do so was to downvote. I ordinarily would not have downvoted the answer, even though I disagree with some of it.

Am I missing something? If not, maybe this functionality could be added?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the "upvote" button again?  I just tried this with your post and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was missing something! Unfortunately my downvote is locked since it's been more than an hour.

Comment: @SilvioLevy You can undo any vote within the first five minutes. You can change your vote after any edit of the original post. You can keep track of all your votes on your profile page. Sometimes it is useful to check back, sometimes things that are done are done...

Comment: @SilvioLevy Jonsca gave you the most appropriate answer.  You may want to accept it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default sorting for answers to questions is by votes.

[image]

If there's an accepted answer, it is at the top of the answers "pile" and the top voted answer is listed immediately below that one.

[image]

The votes are locked in place to prevent users from initially downvoting rival answers to push them down in the pile and then removing the votes later to recoup the 1 reputation point.

From [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70861)

> Basically it's to stop people gaming the system.
>
> One of the ways people did this was by down-voting rival answers and then removing that vote when their answer gains popularity. There are others.

So, the side effect of all this was that legitimate vote changes, like the one you describe, are not allowed either.

Since there are a number of people voting, there's room for a certain amount of "noise" in the system, such that if the answer is of low quality, over the long term downvotes will outnumber any upvotes that were given anyway.

At the risk of being long-winded, the bottom line is there's no need to sweat it.